# How to pass multiple items to a function in handlebars?

Tags: javascript, jquery, handlebars.js

I'm getting the following error in my handlebars file -

" .k="deleteTypePoke({{pokemon_pokemonid,ty
-----------------------^
Expecting 'ID', 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'BOOLEAN', 'UNDEFINED', 'NULL', 'DATA', got 'INVALID'"

Handlebars is not letting me pass both of my variables in, likely due to the comma

```
           {{#each typehaspokemon}}
            <tr>
                    <td>{{pokemonname}}</td>
                    <td>{{typename}}</td>
                    <td><button onclick="deleteTypePoke({{pokemon_pokemonid,type_typeid}})">Delete</button></td>
            </tr>
            {{/each}}
```

Here is my javascript file

```
function deleteTypePoke(pokemon_pokemonid, type_typeid){
        $.ajax({
                url: '/typehaspokemon/' + pokemon_pokemonid + '&' + type_typeid,
                type: 'DELETE',
                success: function(result){
                        window.location.reload(true);
                        }
                })
};
```

How do I pass both the pokemon id AND the type id to this function through handlebars?

Comment: What about `deleteTypePoke({{pokemon_pokemonid}}, {{type_typeid}})`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried this ?:

```
<button onclick="deleteTypePoke({{pokemon_pokemonid}},{{type_typeid}})">Delete</button>
```

Comment: That was it! Thank you